# Matplotlib Event handling

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was playing with this example code for a while now.
http://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/poly_editor.html

1. I want to get a editable line instead of a polygon. I got it done by

   xs = np.arange(0,1,0.1)
   ys = xs*2.0

   but still im getting a filled polygon. How can i just get a line ?

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/As4b2.png)

2. I want to add a button to this so that when I press the button updated x,y pairs will be printed.

How can I get this done.

Thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this statement in place of the similar one in the code.

```
poly = Polygon(list(zip(xs, ys)), animated=True, fc='w')
```

I can't help with adding a button. However, you could put the part of the code that creates the plot in a loop that prints what you want after `plt.show()`, and includes an **input** statement offering the user another opportunity to use the facility before exiting.